# How to ensure a "dotnet tool" is installed in an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dotnet-tool

In a Azure Devop Build, I'm using a tool(https://github.com/tomchavakis/nuget-license). I want this tool to be installed in my Azure Devop Agent.

I've created this task in my YML:

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Install dotnet-project-licenses'
    inputs:
        script: 'dotnet tool install dotnet-project-licenses -g'
```

This works, but only the first time. Then when the tool is already installed, I get an error code.

So how to install this automatically on my agents once? Or swallow the error?

Comment: Do you use custom agents or microsoft hosted agents?

Comment: @GeralexGR Yes I do, but we plan to extends with some cloud agent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running the script as

```
dotnet tool update dotnet-project-licenses -g
```

If the tool isn't installed this command should install it, and if it is already installed it shouldn't give an error

Answer (score 3):

You can add a powershell task instead of the cmd and add the continue on error action. Then your pipeline will continue if it is already installed.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'dotnet tool install dotnet-project-licenses -g'
    errorActionPreference: 'continue'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's a great approach even if I've been able to totally remove the error with @DavidCox88 approach.